# Given `IQueryable<Order>` and `IList<Guid>` gave me all that `Order` whose Id is inside that `IList<Guid>`

Tags: c#, linq

I have an `IQueryable<OrderView>` where `Order` is a complex object:

```
public class OrderView {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

I have a filter extension method that (would) say: Given `IQueryable<Order>` and `IList<Guid>` gave me all that `Order` whose `Id` is inside that `IList<Guid>`

```
public static IQueryable<Order> FilterByOrderIds(this IQueryable<Order> orders, IList<Guid> filter) 
{
    // ...
}
```

So for instance, if `IQueryable<OrderView>` is like:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111",
        "Name": "CPU"
    }, {
        "Id": "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111112",
        "Name": "RAM"
    }, {
        "Id": "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111113",
        "Name": "MOBO"
    }, {
        "Id": "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111114",
        "Name": "MOUSE"
    }
]
```

and `IList<Guid>` contains `11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111112` and `11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111113` the result of `FilterByOrderIds` should be an IQueryable like:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111112",
        "Name": "RAM"
    }, {
        "Id": "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111113",
        "Name": "MOBO"
    }
]
```

I'm trying to do the job with Linq's method syntax, but I'm stuck with incompability among two structure IQueryable and IList.

Comment: Have you tried the obvious `orders.Where(x -> filter.Contains(x.Id))`?

Answer (score 1):

you need to check if the id of your order is in the filter:

```
public static IQueryable<Order> FilterByOrderIds(this IQueryable<Order> orders, IList<Guid> filter) 
{
    return orders.Where(o => filter.Contains(o.Id));
}
```